# IndexError :::list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python.
I wrote a code below.
code is running.
But when I command "pop" from the outside, it gives an error.
because only one word is written for the "pop"
and so it gives "IndexError: list index out of range" error for number variable
ı can how to fix this error?

```
z=int(input())
liste=set(map(int,input().split()))
for _ in range(0,int(input())):
       line=input().split()
       deger=line[0]
       sayi=line[1]--this line give me error for 'pop' command
       if deger=='pop':
           liste.pop()
       elif deger=='remove':
           liste.remove(int(sayi))
       elif deger=='discard':
            liste.discard(int(sayi))
       else:
           pass

for xx in liste:
    print(str(xx),sep="\n")
```

Error:

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: a) why do you access the second element if there is no second element? or b) why do you enter only one item if your program needs 2?

Comment: check `len(line)` before you get `line[1]` or get `line[1]` only inside  `else deger=='remove'` and inside `elif deger=='discard':` when you really need this value.

Comment: thanks . :)The 'len (line)' command that helps a lot .
the code is worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z=int(input())
liste=set(map(int,input().split()))
for _ in range(0,int(input())):
       line=input().split()
       deger=line[0]
       if deger=='pop':
           liste.pop()
       elif deger=='remove':
           sayi = line[1]
           liste.remove(int(sayi))
       elif deger=='discard':
            sayi = line[1]
            liste.discard(int(sayi))
       else:
           pass

for xx in liste:
    print(str(xx),sep="\n")
```

Try this simple solution for your question